# Pyomo ERROR: Constructing component 'obj' from data=None failed: KeyError: ('Berlin', 'Wismar')

Tags: pyomo

I am trying to implement a "simple" 3-echelon product allocation problem with multiple time periods. The mathematical formulation looks like below:
[image]

However, I keep running into the following Error:
None: KeyError: ('Berlin', 'Wismar')
ERROR: Constructing component 'obj' from data=None failed: KeyError:
('Berlin', 'Wismar')

I figured the issue is coming from one of the parameter-indexed sets ("dist[f, w]), but I am not sure how to fix it. I have spent a lot of time on StackOverflow looking for ways to fix it but to no avail. So, I decided to seek help from this community.

I have attached my model file and sample data files for convenience.

Thanks in advance.

```
def product_allocation_acx_whs_model(K, P, F, W, S, D, pcost, tcost, dist1, dist2, turnoverR, wcap):


    model = pyo.ConcreteModel(name="Product_Allocation)")
    
    # todo - declare model decision variables
    model.x = pyo.Var(K, F, P, W, within=pyo.Reals)
    model.y = pyo.Var(S, W, within=pyo.Binary)
    
    # todo - model objective function declaration
    def obj_rule(m):
        return sum(
             m.x[k, f, p, w] * (pcost[k, f, p] + tcost[k, p] * dist1[f, w]) for k in K for f in F for p in P for w in
             W) + \
                sum(D[k, s, p] * tcost[k, p] * dist2[s, w] * m.y[k, s, w] for k in K for s in S for p in P for w in W)
    
     model.obj = pyo.Objective(rule=obj_rule, sense=minimize)
    
    
    # todo - warehs_product_alloc.2 equation - double check this construction
    def demand_c_rule(m, p, f, w, s):
        return sum((m.x[k, p, f, w] for k in K) == sum(m.d[k, s, p] * m.y[k, s, w]) for k in K)
    
    model.obj = pyo.Constraint(F, W, S, rule=demand_c_rule)
    
    # warehs_product_alloc.3 equation - construct the warehouse capacity constraint
    def warehouse_capacity_c_rule(m, p, w, s, d):
        return sum(sum(d[k, s, p] / turnoverR[p]) <= wcap[w] for k in K)
    
    model.wcap = pyo.Constraint(P, W, S, D, rule=warehouse_capacity_c_rule)
    
    # warehs_product_alloc.4 equation - construct the warehouse-sales outlet association constraint
    def warehouse_sales_outlet_association_rule(m, s, w):
        return (m.y[k, s, w] for k in K) == 1  # if a sales outlet is associated with a warehouse
    
    model.assoc = pyo.Constraint(S, W, rule=warehouse_sales_outlet_association_rule)
    
    # warehs_product_alloc.5 equation - construct production non-negativity constraint
    def production_non_negativity(m, p, f, w):
        return sum(m.x[k, p, f, w] for k in K) >= 0  # production must be greater than zero
    
    model.non_negativity = pyo.Constraint(P, F, W, rule=production_non_negativity)
    
    # warehs_product_alloc.6 equation - construct binary (or hard) constraint
    def binary_const(m, s, w):
        for k in K:
            return 0 <= m.y[k, s, w] <= 1  # associating a sales outlet to a warehouse
    
    model.assocBounds = pyo.Constraint(S, W, rule=binary_const)
    
    return model

# todo - dynamic spin on reading a data

def preprocessed_model_data(fpath):
df = pd.read_excel(fpath)

    # time periods
    # K = list(df['Periods(Days)'].map(str))
    K = df['Periods(Days)'].unique().tolist()
    
    # products
    P = list(df.Products.map(str))
    
    # factories
    F = list(df.Factory.map(str))
    
    # warehouses
    W = list(df.Warehouse.map(str))
    
    # sales outlets
    S = list(df['Sales Outlets'].map(str))
    
    # process the data file
    demand, distFW, distWS, upCost, transCostp, turnOR, Wcapty, Pcapty, InvhldCst, EndInvent = {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, \
                                                                                               {}, {}, {}, {}
    
    for i in df.index:
        keyd = (df.at[i, 'Periods(Days)'], df.at[i, 'Sales Outlets'], df.at[i, 'Warehouse'])
        valued = df.at[i, 'Sales']
    
        keydstfw = (df.at[i, 'Factory'], df.at[i, 'Warehouse'])
        valuedstfw = df.at[i, 'Dist Fact-Whse']
    
        keydstws = (df.at[i, 'Warehouse'], df.at[i, 'Sales Outlets'])
        valuedstws = df.at[i, 'Dist Whse-Sales Outlet']
    
        keyuCost = (df.at[i, 'Periods(Days)'], df.at[i, 'Factory'], df.at[i, 'Products'])
        valueuCost = df.at[i, 'Unit Cost of Production']
    
        keyTcost = (df.at[i, 'Periods(Days)'], df.at[i, 'Products'])
        valueTCost = df.at[i, 'Trans Cost']
    
        keyTOR = (df.at[i, 'Periods(Days)'], df.at[i, 'Products'], df.at[i, 'Warehouse'])
        valueTOR = df.at[i, 'Turnover Rate']
    
        keywcap = (df.at[i, 'Periods(Days)'], df.at[i, 'Warehouse'])
        valuewcap = df.at[i, 'Whse Capacity']
    
        dictionary_demand = {keyd: valued}
        demand.update(dictionary_demand)
    
        dictionary_dstfw = {keydstfw: valuedstfw}
        distFW.update(dictionary_dstfw)
    
        dictionary_dstws = {keydstws: valuedstws}
        distWS.update(dictionary_dstws)
    
        dictionary_uCost = {keyuCost: valueuCost}
        upCost.update(dictionary_uCost)
    
        dictionary_TCost = {keyTcost: valueTCost}
        transCostp.update(dictionary_TCost)
    
        dictionary_TOR = {keyTOR: valueTOR}
        turnOR.update(dictionary_TOR)
    
        dictionary_Wcap = {keywcap: valuewcap}
        Wcapty.update(dictionary_Wcap)
    
    return K, P, F, W, S, demand, upCost, transCostp, distFW, distWS, turnOR, Wcapty

# todo - create the model runner function and dataset for the model

def main():
dirpath = '../data/input/'
files_dist = \[fname for fname in os.listdir(dirpath) if fname.endswith('.xlsx') and 'testD' in fname\]

    for efile in files_dist:
        K, P, F, W, S, demand, upCost, transCostp, distFW, distWS, turnOR, Wcapty = preprocessed_model_data(
            dirpath + efile)
    
        # Create the Pyomo model with a call of the model function
        model = product_allocation_acx_whs_model(K, P, F, W, S, demand, upCost, transCostp, distFW, distWS, turnOR,
                                                 Wcapty)
    
        # TODO - solve model instance with local gurobi solver
        opt = pyo.SolverFactory('gurobi')
        res = opt.solve(model)
        pyo.assert_optimal_termination(res)
        # model.write('../data/output/productallocationmodel.lp')
        model.display()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several significant errors in the code.  I strongly suggest a couple things:

1. Start out with a very small subset of your data and get that running.  That way you can inspect the elements, and you can print out the model to QA it with `model.pprint()`.
2. Forget about putting things in separate functions for now.  Just do this whole thing sequentially and it will help you debug it, I think.
3. Do some research on how to get dictionaries out of data frames.  You are doing it wrong--and it should be easy.  The way you are doing it now, you are indexing through the data frame (always a sign of problems) and you are OVERWRITING the items you are putting data into each time in the loop, so they will be incorrect.  Print a couple after the loop to QA.  That is your missing data.
4. In your pyomo model, you are OVERWRITING `model.obj` because you are declaring it twice.  You should be getting a warning for that.
5. In the second (mistaken) declaration of `model.obj` that is attached to `demand_c_rule` your are passing in 3 parameters where the function requires 4 (+ the model).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback AirSquid. But I am only using the 6 sample data. Your point on the dictionary creation and others are noted. I am trying out some of your suggestions now.

Comment: I have crossed the dictionary creation and it is working as expected. For example for "distFW", I am getting the expected output: ```{('Berlin', 'Teltow'): 19.6, ('Hamburg', 'Wismar'): 126.2, ('Berlin', 'Kleinmachnow'): 26.9}```.  Because of the error mentioned earlier, I am unable to print out the ```model.pprint()```. Also, I agree, ```model.obj`` might have some issues. So, I have switched to say using Pyomo ```Epression``` instead: ```model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=model.obj_component1 + model.obj_component2, sense=pyo.minimize)
```
But I'm still getting the same issue(s).